# What is an adjective for a group of people who have already been convinced of something?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, adjectives

I'm looking for a word that could be used to describe a group of people who believe the same thing.

> The members of the blog site worked hard to win others over to their political views, unaware that their follower base was _______.

In this case, their followers already share their views, which, unbeknownst to them, makes their arguments moot.

"Like-minded" is close, but not quite right (perhaps because it lacks the connotation of ignorance), and I would prefer a single concise word.

Comment: Not what you're after, but something along the lines of *preaching to the converted*, *on side*, *aligned*? Any views on these that could help guide an answer?

Comment: Both 'converted' and 'aligned' fit well.  Though those imply that there was a past action that changed their views, as opposed to the followers having always held the views.

Comment: ...their follower base was already within spec. Or ...their follower base was self selecting.

Comment: Why do they need to win over their own followers? Aren't they followers because they follow/support their views already?

Comment: **Determined, decided, etc** are adjectives. Please search for synonyms.

Comment: @NVZ , Yes, of course, but in this case, they have not stopped to think about that fact.  In many cases, people who are preaching to the choir do not realize they are doing so.

Comment: *unaware that their follower base was convinced*...

Comment: There's the ever-popular "true believers".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that "insular" would fit well here.

From M-W, sense 2:

"characteristic of an isolated people; especially :  being, having, or reflecting a narrow provincial viewpoint"

The word also provides the dash of "ignorance" you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

**Choir** — [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/choir)

> 3. an organized group of persons or things

From the expression "Preach to the **choir (or converted)"** — [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/preach+to+the+choir)

> *Fig.* to make one's case primarily to one's supporters; to make one's case only to those people who are present or who are already friendly to the issues.
>
> *"There is no need to convince us of the value of hard work. We already know that. You are just preaching to the choir."*
> *"Bob found himself preaching to the converted when he was telling Jane the advantages of living in the suburbs. She already hates city life."*

Comment: Hey there. Don't you think what you provided actually describes the entire phenomenon instead of giving a word for such a group?

Comment: @vickyace The word I suggested is "choir", the bold parts, but doesn't exactly fit in OP's example given, I know :)

Comment: "Preaching to the choir" is exactly the phenomenon, but yeah, I'm more looking for an adjective to describe the choir in this situation.

Comment: @NVZ This is embarrassing. I'm sorry. I was misled by the collusion of the words "something" in the question title and "same thing" in the detail. Your answer is good, but still isn't an adjective.

Comment: @ThunderGuppy [Congruous](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/congruous)?

Comment: @NVZ I really like 'congruous'.  That's almost spot on to what I was looking for.  It lacks any suggestion of ignorance, but otherwise fits really well.

Comment: @ThunderGuppy Thank you. I'll let you post the answer this time. Add an answer with definition, reference, link and possible examples. :) Answering own questions are highly encouraged.

Answer (score 1):

**Congruous**

*"The members of the blog site worked hard to win others over to their political views, unaware that their follower base was already congruous."*

From [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/congruous):

> 1.
>   a :  being in agreement, harmony, or correspondence
>   b :  conforming to the circumstances or requirements of a situation :  appropriate 
>   2. marked or enhanced by harmonious agreement among constituent elements

Answer (score 0):

Try the simple word [allied](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/allied) defined by Merriam Webster as

> Having or being in close association
>
> Joined in alliance by compact or treaty.

Something sophisticated would be [federated](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/federated) defined by Merriam Webster as

> United in an alliance

Also see [Confederated](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/confederate)